# Multiple controller interaction

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is what I'm trying to do. A button in PipelineController view starts an address verification process.

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ3sX/4/

```
 <button type="submit" class="form-group btn btn-default" data-ng-    click="startPipeLineAddressCheck(selectedRow.address)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;Verify     Address
                    </button>
```

This fires a broadcast message that two controllers are subscribed to: PipelineController and AddressCheckerController. The view for the address verification has AddressCheckerController set as ng-controller. AddressCheckerController is supposed to launch the modal but it looks like the controller isn't "loaded". I don't see the debug alerts I put in.

So I have 2 issues. The first is I don't see the AddressCheckerController catching to broadcast, then the modal isn't showing *but* that's most likely due to the controller not being available. So for now any help getting the AddressCheckerController running would be greatly appreciated. I'll worry about the modal later :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ui-bootstrap!

```
var appRoot = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngResource', 
    'angularStart.services', 
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

Comment: that helps some...The address controller is now catching the broadcast but the modal isn't showing. I'll keep debugging and try to find out what I messed up. Thank you!!!